# Then why didn't you come? / Why didn't you come then?

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

Are "then why didn't you come?" and "why didn't you come then?" always completely interchangeable and equally natural?

Example

> A: I thought we had an appointment. Did I bore you last time or...?

> B: No.

> A: Then why didn't you come? / Why didn't you come, then?

Comment: They should have the exact same meaning, I don't think there's any difference (might be a slight difference in tone maybe)

Answer (score -1):

Then implies a time in the past, which is already implied by using the past tense of "to come".

So it would be like saying

> Why didn't you come then, in the past, before now.

In some cases, the additional emphasis on the past might have an emotional appeal, or be used to focus strongly on the past element of the statement; but, it doesn't change the meaning.

In some kinds of arguments, drawing attention to the points you want to highlight merit repeating elements.

> The dress was a brilliant sunshine, buttercup, fresh-paint yellow.

But in other speech, it is not necessary to bring such focus.

> The dress was yellow.

Using "then" alone with the past tense doesn't do a good job of emphasizing the past more; but, it is very natural when someone has already referred to a point of time in the past.

> Why didn't you come then?

makes a lot of sense in the conversation.

> Monday of last week, you were near your destination.  Why didn't you come then?
>
> I was going to come on Tuesday.

Now the phrase

> Then why didn't you come?

Can have a very different meaning.  Then can also refer to a reason instead of a time, as in the example:

> Last week, on Monday you were near your destination.  Then why didn't you come?
>
> I already made an appointment to come at another time.

So, generally the putting the "then" after a reference to time binds the meaning to time, while putting it before the time leaves it bound to prior ideas, and leading with it leaves it unbound altogether.

Comment: The meaning depends on the intonation. "Why didn't you come _then_?" means _at that time_. "Why didn't you _come_, then?" - with comma - means the same as "Then why didn't you come?"

Comment: @KateBunting Well, it would mean "Then, why didn't you come?"  but without the comma, one needs to go with context, because Adverbial modifiers are used both ways: "Recently, I ate a sandwich."  "Recently I ate a sandwich."  The problem is not the comma, but the dual-meanings associated with the word "then."

Comment: I see the two versions quoted by the OP as involving the _same_ meaning of _then_ - (in that case).